# Kubernetes LoadBalancer Service returning empty response

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

1. node.js express server bound to port 8080

```
server.listen(8080, () => {
  logger.log({
    level: 'info',
    message: 'Listening on port ' + port
  })
})
```

2. Docker image with node.js code + npm modules with port 8080 exposed

```
FROM node:10-alpine

...

# Expose port
EXPOSE 8080
```

3. Kubernetes deployment of Docker image with containerPort 8080 configured

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: deployment

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deployment

  replicas: 2

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deployment

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: job-id-20
        image: redacted/redacted
        command: ["node", "backend/services.js"]

        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 8080

      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-hub-credentials

      dnsConfig:
        options:
          - name: ndots
            value: "0"
```

4. Kubernetes service with matching selector to app with targetPort of 8080 and type LoadBalancer

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:
  name: service

spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080

  selector:
    app: deployment

  type: LoadBalancer
```

5. Verify load balancer has external IP (I scrubbed it)

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig="k8s-1-13-4-do-0-nyc1-1552761372568-kubeconfig.yaml" get service/service
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
service   LoadBalancer   10.245.239.60   1x4.2x9.1x8.x2   8080:30626/TCP   113s
```

6. curl fails with empty response

```
$ curl --verbose http://1x4.2x9.1x8.x2:8080/
*   Trying 1x4.2x9.1x8.x2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 1x4.2x9.1x8.x2 (1x4.2x9.1x8.x2) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 1x4.2x9.1x8.x2:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 1x4.2x9.1x8.x2 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I'd expect the traffic to route through to the service to one of the pods/replicas in the deployment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m assuming the pod is not failing, node.js code is not returning an error? What happens if you change the service to a `NodePort` and try curling the node ip & port?

Comment: If you use `docker run` to run the same image outside of Kubernetes, is it reachable?

Comment: To debug further, ```k describe svc service``` see endpoints are attached. Next step,  ```k exec deployment/deployment-somepodhash sh``` to check whether `http://localhost:8080` is working or not. If none of them are working then it is a network setup issue. Final step, do `iptables -t nat -L KUBE-SERVICES` to figure out services attached.

Comment: Are u able to curl from inside the POD ?

Comment: did you solve this problem ? actually i am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Have you checked if the pods are returning the correct response or not by using curl the pod IP from within the cluster?

Comment: Hello, I've managed to reproduce the same error with as close as possible code to the one included in the question and the empty response was produced with the server.get(`/`, (req, res) => { }) (no `res.send("MESSAGE"`).

Comment: I had a similar issue with `rails server`... The problem was not the port, but the **network interface** (IP). My server was listening on `127.0.0.1:3000` instead of  `0.0.0.0:3000`

Comment: OMG, thank you @collimarco, has the same issue because I was running NodeJS server on `localhost:3000`, changed to `0.0.0.0:3000` - works perfect

Answer (score 3):

There are some potential sources of errors here.

First potential problem is that your Docker image does not work as expected.  You can try this: Use `nginx:latest` as your image and try if this works. If this works the Kubernetes parts are working correctly and you can do further investigation on your Docker image.

Your code snippet does not contain any code that outputs some data as far as I can see.

You can experiment with your image by using the `docker run` command as indicated in the comments above.

If it still does not work with the Nginx image then you have to further investigate the Kubernetes side.

Although a LoadBalancer is a standard Kubernetes service type, its implementation is different for different cloud providers and on-premise installations.

You must consult your Kubernetes or cloud provider's documentation on how to find out if the LoadBalancer is configured correctly.

To see if the service can reach the pods you can use the command `kubectl get endpoints`.

To do some more debugging you can use the `kubectl port-forward` command to create a tunnel to either one of the pods or to the service and try the curl command on the established tunnel.

Also you can use the `kubectl logs` command to see any log output of your pods.

Answer (score -1):

Check any error while creating image ,check if pods were successfully deployed after deployment i.e. they should be in running state and check for service too.
if these are conditions are correct than I hardly see any error in you steps.
Here is a simple example for nodejs application deployment .

index.js

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World!");

});

var port = 80;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

Docker File:

```
FROM node:0.10.40
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./nodejs-docs-hello-world ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

web-deployement:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: imagename
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http-server
```

web-service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    name: web
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: web
```

Comment: Please check the Pod logs for any errors and see if you can ping the pod and get the reply back.